# Unable to stop try_for_each_concurrent for mongodb client

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a GRPC endpoint that streams results from Cursor. To achieve this I'm using `.map_ok` and `try_for_each_concurent` methods. I'm using the *try* version of for each because I would like to stop the loop if any error occurs.

I'm experiencing an issue with trying to stop try_for_each_concurrent because is expecting me to return `mongodb::error::Error` and I'm unable to create it.

How to create mongodb error?

here is a snippet of code :-)

```rust
let mongo_db_collection_stream = mongo_db_collection_stream.map_ok(|doc| {
    let parse_result: Result<Asset, _> = from_bson(Bson::Document(doc));
    parse_result
});

mongo_db_collection_stream.try_for_each_concurrent(None, |vs_or_err| {
    let mut tx_copy = tx.clone();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        tx_copy.send(vs_or_err.clone()).await.unwrap();
    });

    async {
        match vs_or_err {
            Ok(v) => Ok(()),
            Err(v) => Err((v)),
        }
    }
}).await;
```

output from console

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<impl futures::Future as futures::Future>::Output == Result<(), mongodb::error::Error>`
   --> file.rs:101:9
    |
101 | /         mongo_db_collection_stream.try_for_each_concurrent(None, |vs_or_err| {
102 | |             let mut tx_copy = tx.clone();
103 | |
104 | |             tokio::spawn(async move {
...   |
113 | |             }
114 | |         }).await;
    | |________________^ expected struct `mongodb::error::Error`, found enum `mongodb::bson::de::Error`
```

FYI looks like `mongodb::bson::de::Error` for not implement trait into `mongodb::error::Error`

Comment: Its hard to answer when the code sample is incomplete. However, the conversion trait `From` is implemented for `bson::de::Error` to `mongodb::error::Error` ([1](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.2.2/mongodb/error/struct.Error.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) [2](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.2.2/mongodb/error/enum.ErrorKind.html#impl-From%3CError%3E)). So you should be able to do `Err(v) => Err(v.into())`.

Comment: Hello @kmdreko I forgot about .into! function I tried used from :-)